# Is there a way to remove this black bar over the first suggestion of Eclipse auto-complete for mac?

Tags: java, eclipse

This black bar in Eclipse autocomplete for Mac is always covering the first suggestion for auto-complete. Is there a way to remove/hide it?
[image: example] (under the bar is name1)

Comment: I don't get this with Eclipse 2019-09 on macOS 10.15.1 - what version of Eclipse and macOS are you using?

Comment: That doesn't look like the built-in dark theme. This might be an issue caused by a plugin you have installed.